# How to apply the tempo extracted from track 1 to other tracks of a MIDI file?

Tags: java, audio, midi, javasound

I am trying to extract the tempo of a melody from the first track of a midi file and apply it to the rest of the tracks containing the note events.

Bascically I've been trying to replace the `Thread.sleep()` method after the `noteOn()` message which is playing a note for a fixed time interval everytime. Hence I'm losing the tempo of the entire track.

I was successful in extracting the tempo information from the first track from a previously asked question [How does Midi TEMPO message apply to other tracks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080297/how-does-midi-tempo-message-apply-to-other-tracks) but am unable to apply it to the rest of the tracks.

Is there a particular function that does that? I tried searching but couldn't find one.

Here is my code for reference.

```
      int trackNumber = 0;

     for (Track track :  sequence.getTracks()) {

        trackNumber++;           
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0; i < track.size(); i++) { 

            MidiEvent event = track.get(i);
            MidiMessage message = event.getMessage();

            if (message instanceof MetaMessage) {

             MetaMessage mm = (MetaMessage) message;
             if(mm.getType()==SET_TEMPO){ 

               byte[] data = mm.getData();
               int tempo = (data[0] & 0xff) << 16 | (data[1] & 0xff) << 8 | (data[2] & 0xff);
               int bpm = 60000000 / tempo;
             }
            }

           if (message instanceof ShortMessage) {
                ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) message;
                if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_ON) {

                    int key = sm.getData1();
                    int velocity = sm.getData2();                    
                    channels[0].noteOn(key,velocity);
                    Thread.sleep(280);//Pays all the note for fixed duration    
                } 
                else if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_OFF) {

                    int key = sm.getData1();
                    int velocity = sm.getData2();
                    channels[0].noteOff(key);

                } 
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just clone SetTempo events from the first track and [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Track.html#add(javax.sound.midi.MidiEvent)) cloned instances to other tracks with the same timestamps.

Comment: Did you revise your method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events in multiple tracks happen concurrently, so you cannot handle the tracks separately.

You have to either

- put all events into a single list, and sort them by their timestamp (but ensure that events with the same time stamp keep their order, so use a stable sorting algorithm); or
- have a current position for each track, and when determining which event is the next, search through all the tracks for a yet-unused event with the smallest timestamp.

Please note that the tempo can change during playback, so a single `bpm` value does not suffice. See [How to correctly convert MIDI ticks to milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34166367/11654) and [How can I parse a tempo of midi using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26555718/11654).

Comment: From what I have understood, after sorting the events according to their timestamp values I should be passing the delta time value evaluated from it as a parameter to the `Thread.sleep(millisec)` function. Let me know if this is what you have been trying to explain. Thanks.

Comment: Ticks are not milliseconds, and the delta times are between events in a single track. After sorting, you have to compute the timer interval between adjacent events again.

Comment: What do you mean by adjacent events ? You'd have the formula to compute that interval ?

Comment: @Stephane See the linked questions.